# Question fit for other SE site put on hold - ask moderator move or recreate (and delete)?

Tags: support, migrated-questions, on-hold

The comment under this [Close vote review](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/close/16109):

> Not a cross-post, my question was put on hold because it didn't fit the rpg SE and I was recommended to post it here instead

made me wonder:

**If a question is put on hold on X.SE because it is not a good fit there, but it is fine for Y.SE, what should the OP do?**

- Flag for moderator attention with request to move?
- Recreate it on Y.SE?
- Recreate it on Y.SE and delete it on X.SE?
- Other...

*Assume there is no default close reason to have it move to Y.SE, and for simplicity, that the question quality is OK*

Follow-up detail question in case the answer is 'ask mod move':
Will the question still have status 'On hold' when migrated to Y.SE?

Comment: Migrations always reopen questions. (Because all questions are expected to be closed, at least notionally, before being migrated at all; a question that should not be closed is a question that should not be migrated.)

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do it (and the one most widely accepted by the SE communities) is to

- Flag for moderator attention with request to move.

But it can take awhile for a moderator to notice the flag and move the question.  Nearly functionally equivalent is

- Recreate it on Y.SE and delete it on X.SE.

But for whatever reason, it seems that users are reluctant to delete things that they have posted, thereby leaving it to the community to clean up after the mess they have left behind.

From a practical standpoint, either strategy is perfectly fine.  Obviously I would prefer that people flag for migration with a detailed explanation, but not everyone has the time to wait, and it's much easier to just do it yourself, if you can clean up after yourself.

However, for a migration to occur, the question has to be squarely on-topic for the target site, and a pretty high quality question to begin with.  The odds of someone posting a qualified question, but posting it to the wrong site, are fairly small; usually off-topic questions are not of sufficient quality to justify migration to another site.